# Problem Booting Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04

Can anyone help me through this. I unplugged my 2TB HDD from my Computer as it has seriously important data. I plugged my new 4TB HDD and boot up a Ubunut 14.04 LTS live on flash. I formatted the Drive into one 4TB partition and then I unplugged my Flash drive. I then plugged both drives and since then my server keeps telling that it does not find any boot device!!! Even if I remove the 4TB and keep the initial configuration as it was.

Answer (score 0):

It just sounds like you need to install grub to the 4TB disk, or set in your BIOS to boot the 2TB disk first since the bootloader is installed there. Your 2TB disk is probably not sda anymore since you replaced it, and not the first disk that is being checked for a bootloader.

To Install grub:

1. Boot from an ubuntu live usb

   Mount your drives under the /mnt directory

   Chroot into that directory with `chroot /mnt`

   Then run `grub install /dev/sda` to install grub.

Comment: I think, that might be the case but I have a concern. Does in anyways doing this stuff destroy my data on the disk?

Comment: Installing grub won't. It just installs to the first 512Mb of your hard drive (first Gb or so with UEFI) where no user data exists. It will redetect your installs and partitions and allow the bios to find the os when booting.

Comment: You are very welcome!